# XSLT Rename Element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document and I want to rename some elements via XSLT:

```
<Assert @some attributes here>
  <conent>
    <And>
      <formula>
        <Atom>
          <opr>
...
```

For example I want to rename `<opr>` to `<op>`. I have the following XSLT:

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="opr">
    <op>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </op>
  </xsl:template>
```

When I debug the XSLT it just doesn't go inside the "opr" template, it gets matched by the first template. The generated output is the same as the input. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Im sure this was asked a few days ago?

Comment: Do you really want to be trying to match all attributes or do you just want to ensure all attributes are copied to the new node?

Comment: I just want every to be copied, just rename opr to op

Comment: Your example XSLT works fine for me using `xsltproc`. (Tried with stylesheet: http://pastebin.com/f325b0978 and input: http://pastebin.com/f3b69d3b4, got output: http://pastebin.com/m2a26b8dd). Please post the complete XSLT and input file you are testing with, not just fragments. Does the `opr`-matching template happen to be in an imported stylesheet, therefore getting lower import precedence? Does anything change if you explicitly set higher priority to the `opr`-matching template (try `priority="1"`).

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template name="YourNameHere">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="opr">
    <op>
      <xsl:call-template name="YourNameHere"/>
    </op>
  </xsl:template>
```

You'll probably still need something like <xsl:template match="/" /> to get it going.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
<xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="opr">
        <op>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </op>
</xsl:template>
```